# Node Express TypeORM createConnection fails

Tags: node.js, express, typeorm

To test TypeORM, I try to set up a Node Express app on a remote server. On localhost, the following code works. The server throws a 503 error after pending has been completed after a while.
Here is the .ts code but on the server, I uploaded the compiled .js code.
Thanks in advance for your help.

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es5", "es6", "dom"],
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  }
}
```

ormconfig.json

```
{
  "type": "mysql",
  "host": "myhost",
  "port": 3306,
  "username": "myusername",
  "password": "mypassword",
  "database": "mydatabase",
  "entities": ["src/entity/*.js"],
  "logging": true,
  "synchronize": true
}
```

src/app.ts

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import * as express from "express";
import {Request, Response} from "express";
import {createConnection} from "typeorm";
import {User} from "./entity/User";

createConnection().then(connection => {
    const userRepository = connection.getRepository(User);

    const app = express();
    app.use(express.json());

    app.get("/users", async function(req: Request, res: Response) {
        const users = await userRepository.find();
        res.json(users);
    });

    app.listen();
  });
```

src/entity/User.ts

```
import {Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn} from "typeorm";

@Entity()
export class User {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    firstName: string;

    @Column()
    lastName: string;
}
```

Comment: Could you please share the request to server that you send?

Comment: Sorry, I might not understand it correctly. What do you mean by 'request'? I call the endpoint https://maraxai.com/maraxai/test-gql-prisma/typeorm-users/users in the browser.

Comment: please try to set port for app.listen();, example: app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
}) and route for testing: app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
});

Comment: The console.log is displayed only in the terminal on localhost. That's why I did not use it. The Hello-World-testcode works on the server. The problem is the function createConnection().